# upload a file using spring MultipartFile and google app engine

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have been trying to upload a file by using MVC and Google App engine. Every time i am getting the error like

**Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?**

After that i have referred two tutorials to upload a file. Everytime the flow goes to the controller but can able to get access to the MultipartFile file that is uploaded in the jsp file using Spring MVC and Google App engine. The two references are

http://alasdoo.com/2010/10/how-to-upload-a-file-with-spring-mvc-3-and-google-app-engine/

https://code.google.com/p/gmultipart/

so any one can guide me whats the wrong in the references to resolve the issues.

Comment: Are you willing to upload to file system or in Blobstore, as you cannot upload the file to file system.

Comment: There is no need to add any MultipartFileResolver. Just write a method which will return you an upload URL, on that particular method do the **enctype/multipart-formdata** post, you will get the file uploaded to Blobstore.

Comment: i tried, but no use. And came back to the jsp-servlet mechanism to store it. but i want to directly sore to the datastore with reading it.

Comment: Please find my code below for Spring GAE File Upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following method will return a callback URL on which you need to post your file(s).

**Upload Url Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getImageUploadUrl() {
    modelMap.addAttribute('uploadUrl',blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/imageupload));
    return "upload";
}
```

Following is the JSP snippet where you will embed your code. I am putting the URL in **form tag** using **JSTL**.

**JSP Page**

```
<form action="${uploadUrl}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" multiple="multiple" />
</form>
```

**Upload Handler Method**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getUploadedImagesUrls(HttpServletRequest request){
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile[]");
    if (blobKeys == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        for(BlobKey blobKey : blobKeys){
            // ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
            // ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
            // String imageUrl = services.getServingUrl(serve);
            BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
            BlobInfo info = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
            System.out.println("Image URL : "+imageUrl);
            System.out.println("Image FileName : "+info.getFilename());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post Jain. But i am not going to upload a image. It may any file of any size.

Comment: No issue, you can skip the Image services part and anyways you will get the blobkey of the image which you can use to download/delete and get info about the bolb.

Comment: check if you have file uploaded check under **localhost:8888/_ah_admin**

Comment: Well there is no any such way as far as I know that you can read the contents of a file, as Appengine doesn't care about what kind of file you are actually uploading to it. Although I think you can try to upload the file by using Apache File Upload Library as well in which the controller will upload the whole file to Blobstore, and you can try there if you can read it contents.

Comment: tq. can we call it by using ajax? I mean i just want to call the method **/imageupload** by using ajax. By using ajax the method is not get invoked.