# Does anyone know how to upload multiple files using Blobstore in Java?

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I am submitting a form which has a upload filed and other fields , I writing other fields to database using j-query ajax but having issue with the upload..looks like I will have to separate the the file upload from rest of the form..  Is there a way to use Blob store upload without redirection ?

This is the  functionality i want to achieve with Blobstore and Java App Engine

1. Allows the user to select multiple files.
2. Ajax send the files to the GAE server.
3. Save the files in GAE server.
4. Return the links to the file.
5. Add the uploaded files to the current page.

It Would be nice if any Google Developer post a Java reference code

Comment: You can use this plugin for uploading multiplr file. http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: Also for this situation you need to do some workaround that get a callback url first and then upload file using AJAX. You can refer to my answer for similar query here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421460/upload-a-file-using-spring-multipartfile-and-google-app-engine/23425398#23425398