# Google App Engine Image service with Android

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, authentication, parse-platform

I am building an Android app which lets the user to upload photos and share it with other users as well.
I decided to use Parse Backend service because it's too easy with dealing with data and users and uploading photos but there is an issue that parse does not support image on fly service.

I have looked around and found that Google App Engine has image service which supports image on fly.

So the application will send the an Image file to GAE and Get A URL and store that URL in Parse Cloud and when any user wants to download that Image he will use the URL which contains image on fly service.

So what I want to do is to use Parse backend with Facebook authentication for Parse cloud services With GAE image services for users to upload and download images.

I have read in the documentations that authentication is required in order to use any of GAE services
I don't want to make another User authentication procedure I want any user in my App upload and retrieve images without authentication by Google account/apps.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Please refer to this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306790/how-can-i-upload-an-thumbnail-image-blob-at-the-same-time-as-an-entity-into-a/15309278#15309278

Comment: Also here I have provided the sample for the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421460/upload-a-file-using-spring-multipartfile-and-google-app-engine/23425398#23425398

Comment: thanks for your reply but what about the authentication ?

Comment: you don't need any authentication for uploading. just test, run an deploy.